# appendColumn bahaving like appendRow

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qtreeview

I'm trying to make a Tree:

So for I have set the first column right using this:

```
self._populate_tree(data, self.tree_model.invisibleRootItem())

def _populate_tree(self, children, parent):
    for child in sorted(children):
        child_item = QStandardItem(str(child))
        parent.appendRow(child_item)
        self._populate_tree(children[child], child_item)
```

A sample data is like so:

```
data = {'Day 1': 
               {'Completed': 
                    {'CR_10': 2, 'M_12': 1, 'RE_23': 1}, 
                'Missed': 
                    {'WM_11': 1, 'DW_5': 2, 'BT_22': 1},
                'Score': '-6'
               }
}
```

It populates the tree with the strings(Day 1, Completed, Missed, CR_10...), But it doesn't add the numbers.

Since it raises a error in the recursion if the type of children is a not a dict ( it can't access children[child])

I them made type check:

```
if type(children) == dict:
    # above code ...
else:
    parent.appendColumn([QStandardItem(str(children))])
```

But strangly it behaves the same as using `parent.appendRow(QStandardItem(str(children)))`

It places the number as a child of the current item. I want to place it beside, same row, next column.

Currently I have this:

[image]

But I want this instead:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the column count of the model in order to show the second column:

```
    root_model = QStandardItemModel()
    root_model.setColumnCount(2)
```

and you also need to add the row of child items as a list:

```
def _populate_tree(self, children, parent):
    for child in sorted(children):
        child_item = QStandardItem(str(child))
        row = [child_item]
        if isinstance(children[child], dict):
            self._populate_tree(children[child], child_item)
        else:
            item = QStandardItem(str(children[child]))
            row.append(item)
        parent.appendRow(row)
```